# conditional query in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need to provide some status on items in my table which I do in the last column of my table.
First I go and query one table to see if I have a confirmation for the item .

```
<cfquery name="focnotice" datasource="******" result="FocResult">
    SELECT ecspc  
    FROM   tbl_CNR_H 
    WHERE  icsc = '#myarray[i].ICSC#' 
    AND    asr_no = '#myarray[i].ASR#'
</cfquery>
```

The `ECSPC` is a field in my Table, so logic is see if there is a record. If so, see if the `ECSPC` value is something other then "". If so, query another table to see if there is a matching record for this ECSPC.

```
<cfset ISUPStatus = "#focnotice.ecspc#">
<cfif ISUPStatus NEQ "">
    <cfquery name="isupStatus" datasource="******" result="ISUPResult">
        select * 
        from   tbl_ISUP 
        where  dpc = '#ISUPStatus#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfset isupcount = #ISUPResult.RecordCount#>
    <cfif #isupcount# GT 0>
        <cfset ISUPorder = "Yes">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset ISUPorder = "No">
    </cfif>

<cfelse>
    <cfset ISUPorder = "No">
</cfif>
```

I get the following error in my debug

> Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
>
> The expression has requested a variable or an intermediate expression
>   result as a simple value. However, the result cannot be converted to a
>   simple value. Simple values are strings, numbers, boolean values, and
>   date/time values. Queries, arrays, and COM objects are examples of
>   complex values. The most likely cause of the error is that you tried
>   to use a complex value as a simple one. For example, you tried to use
>   a query variable in a cfif tag.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Exactly which line is throwing the error? Why not just use a sql JOIN instead of all the if/else logic?

Comment: I'm looking at your question, but some glaring coding issues make me want to comment on them:
1. <cfset ISUPStatus = focnotice.ecspc> (notice quotes and hash)
5. use <cfqueryparam>, don't use "*" - instead use column names
9. <cfset isupcount = ISUPResult.RecordCount> (notice hash)
10. <cfif isupcount> (notice shorthand and hash)

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem, which was due to crappy codding on my side. I used <cfset ISUPStatus = "#focnotice.ecspc#"> as well gave the new query the name cfquery name="isupStatus" which was the issue. Original it was either "" or had a value but once I used the same name for query name it became complex I could no longer just display it. So I change queryname and that did the job and works as expected

Comment: A few other things you should look into for improving the code 1) Using a JOIN instead of all that if/else logic would simplify the code a lot 2) Always use `cfqueryparam` on variable query parameters. Especially on queries executed multiple times. It uses bind variables to improve performance, and more importantly protects your database against sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing invalid parameter into the Query "myarray[i].ICSC",'#myarray[i].ASR#'. You need to specify what index of array you are using.

```
<cfquery name="focnotice" datasource="*******" result="FocResult">
 Select ecspc
 From tbl_CNR_H
 Where icsc = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#myarray[1].ICSC#">
        AND
      asr_no = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#myarray[1].ASR#"> 
</cfquery>
```

Comment: are you running a query inside a loop? I mean, how are you getting the value of index "i"?

Comment: yes its inside a loop, I have the table in an array and loop thru it, that's why the I for the row in the array

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error causing you the issue lies in:

```
<cfset isupcount = #ISUPResult.RecordCount#>
```

From a quick look of your code, try using instead:

```
<cfset isUpCount = isUpStatus.recordCount>
```

But in addition please look at the comments above, especially joins.

Comment: I suggest dumping out your vars and determine what var you are referencing as a simple object and is really a complex object